# Feature inconsistence with pure JS, throught requireJS, when binding listeners to shortcuts

Tags: javascript, dom, callback, requirejs

I've organized the JS part into modules, using a library called RequireJS. It is working fine but recently I found a very inconsistent bug in Firefox (which is the only browser we need to support to - although until now everything is working ok in Chrome also).
First of all I have a big file called `util.js` which I load in other parts to setup basic functions I use to abstract the DOM, the most important part of it to understand the problem is this:

```
"use strict";
define(function() {
  ...
  Util.killCtrl = function(action) {
    return function(event) {
      if(event.ctrlKey) {
        action && action(event);
        if(!Util.intersection([72, 76, 82], [event.keyCode]).length)
          event.preventDefault();
      } 
  };
  Util.intersection = function(a, b) {
    return a.filter(function(e) {
      return b.indexOf(e) != -1;
    });
  }
  ... 
  return Util;
});
```

I simply use this function to make it easy binding custom shortcuts, like `CTRL+P`. When using in the following code, it works perfectly (this is a controller which file is called `sale.js`):

```
"use strict";

define(['util', 'basic', 'language', 'restrict/models/orderItem', 'modal', 'tableSelector'], 
    function(Util, Basic, lang, OrderItem, Modal, TableSelector) {
  ...
  addEventListener('keyup', Util.killCtrl(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 66: //B -> search prod
        searchProd.click();
        break;
      case 80: //P -> print order
        print.click();
        break;
      case 69: //E -> remove prod
        removeProd.click();
        break;
      case 46: //DEL -> quick remove prod
        var selectedPos = tableSelector.getSelectedRow()[0]; 
        deletePos(selectedPos);
        break;
      case 86: //V -> back
        back.click();
        break;
      case 67: //C -> focus code
        OrderItem.orderItems = Util.woIndex(OrderItem.orderItems);
        OrderItem.orderItems = Util.woIndex(OrderItem.orderItems);
        form.code.focus();
        break;
      case 68: //D -> detail item
        var pos = tableSelector.getSelectedRow()[0];        
        var orderItem = OrderItem.orderItems.filter(function(oi) { return oi.displayOrder == pos })[0];
        detailForm.displayOrder.value = orderItem.displayOrder;
        detailForm.name.value = orderItem.name;
        detailForm.amount.value = orderItem.amount;
        Basic.syncNF(detailForm.amount);
        detailButton.click();
        break;
      case 81: //Q -> focus amount
        amountFacade.focus();
    }
  }));
  ...
});
```

The same thing doesn't work properly in the following controller, `billing.js`:

```
define(['util', 'basic', 'language', 'restrict/models/payer', 'restrict/models/paymentType', 
    'restrict/models/payment'], function(Util, Basic, lang, Payer, PaymentType, Payment) {
  ...
  addEventListener('keyup', Util.killCtrl(function(event) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case 80: // P
        printButton.click();
        break; 
    }
  }));  
  ...
});
```

In this time it is opening the default print screen from browser, instead of running the command I gave!! The other controller functionalities are pretty fine, and there is no problem in `billing.js` but this.
All the controllers are loaded with a file called `main.js`, here it goes:

```
"use strict";
require(['util', 'basic'], function(Util, Basic) {
  if(Basic.verifyPlaces('sale/fastSelling')) {
    var requirements = ['restrict/sale', 'dynamicSearch'];
    require(requirements);
  } 
  else if(Basic.verifyPlaces('billing/receipt')) { require(['restrict/billing']); }
  else if(Basic.verifyPlaces('sale/tables')) { require(['restrict/access']); }
});
```

All files are being loaded because all functionalities are up and running except this, Have you ever faced any similar problem?

I did some logs, in the `preventDefault` part from `util.js` and sometimes (like when using `CTRL+I`) it opens **Page Info** together with the log, and other times (like when using `CTRL+P`) it opens **PRINT** and doesn't log anything.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I used `killCtrl` over the `"keyup"` events, when I registered it to `"keydown"` and it worked fine